# Increment a progress bar while a thread executes in the background

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, progress-bar

As a part of a bigger program I've implemented a module (based on a tutorial) with a procedure to send an email when I call the `SendEmail(Recipient, MessageBody)` Sub

```
Public Sub SendEmail(ByVal Recipient As String, ByVal MessageBody As String)
        Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient
        Dim Email As New MailMessage

        With SmtpServer
            .UseDefaultCredentials = False
            .Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("abcd@abcd.com", "abcd")
            .Port = 587
            .EnableSsl = True
            .Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
        End With

        With Email
            .From = New MailAddress("xyz@xyz.com")
            .To.Add(Recipient)
            .Subject = "Arrival reminder"
            .IsBodyHtml = False
            .Body = MessageBody
        End With
        SmtpServer.Send(Email)
End Sub
```

This works pretty well but it takes few seconds to send the mail. If I run this on the main thread, the program becomes unresponsive so I'm using a different thread.

```
Private Sub btnSend_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSend.Click
            Dim MailX = Sub()
                           SendEmail(txtEmail.Text, txtMessage.Text)
                        End Sub
            Dim MailThread As New Thread(MailX)
            MailThread.IsBackground = True
            MailThread.Start()
End Sub
```

I'm not 100% clear on using Lambda expressions but I managed the above from what I collected from the internet.

My question is, How can I increment a progress bar as soon as I call `MailThread.Start()` and stop it (progress bar) when the thread is executed?

Comment: Pretty standard mistake.  You have no idea whatsoever that, say, half the email was sent.  Might take 1 second, if the server is busy it will take twice as long or more.  You therefore cannot meaningfully display progress, you just don't know how far along it got.  All you can do is display "I'm working on it, things are happening and I'm not dead".  Set the ProgressBar.Style to Marquee.

Comment: Thank you very much. It makes sense. I switched to a `BackgroundWorker` instead of a thread and used the button click to start the `BackgroundWorker` along with the progress bar and stopped the progress bar on `BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted` event. It works perfectly.

Comment: Next time use the SendAsync() method instead.